# Windows 7 (roaming profiles) not seeing printers deployed with printer management?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, printing, roaming-profile

I've got a network with about 15-20 printers deployed using printer management that is setup on a Win 2008 server.
All the users have roaming profiles.

All the XP machines get all the printers without issue and the users can print to them all without issue.

I've got at least 1-2 users who are on Windows 7 boxes that see no printers;  I cannot figure out why and am not sure where to look.  The GPO's are getting pushed out and applied to those boxes (I did gpresult and gpupdate /force) but these users still see 0 printers.  I have confirmed that they are in the correct groups to be getting those printers also in AD.

Any and all ideas welcome - I'm stumped.

Comment: First step - is this is a user specific or a machine specific issue? Get a user from a working machine to log on to one of the machines with issues, and vice versa. Then let us know.

Comment: There's more than one way to assign/install printers using GPO, which one are you using at the moment?

Comment: I logged on as other users who have not had printer issues and they too were limited in the printers they saw which I think is a strong indicator there is something going on with the GPO related to her PC specifically.  When that user went to another Win7 machine that worked for others, she saw all her printers there.  This gives me a great direction to keep digging.  GAThrawn - I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean; perhaps my knowledge is more limited than I thought (could you expand on your thought?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a driver issue with regards to the operating systems.  We didn't have 64-bit drivers for some of the newer OS's that had been delivered on the print management server.  Once we got those on there the printers started showing up without issue.

What a simple answer - I was kicking myself :-P